# How do I convert a string to currency with two decimal places in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, string, ms-access

How do I format the following result in currency with 2 decimal places?

```
string query2 = "SELECT SUM (Price) FROM Bill";
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query2, DBconn);
DataTable source = new DataTable();
dAdapter2.Fill(source);
TotalValueLabel.Text = source.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TotalValueLabel.Text = source.Rows[0][0].ToString("c");
```

Comment: I get an error when i try to add "C" 
"No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguements

Comment: What is the error message?  Are you include quotes around "c"?

Comment: Error message as the above. Yep included "C"

Comment: Whoops, gotta cast it to a decimal first: TotalValueLabel.Text =  ((decimal)source.Rows[0][0]).ToString("c");

Comment: BTW, if this field allows for null you should alter the code appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Some `ToString` overloads accepts format strings that allow you to specify the configuration of the output (this depends on class). For currency (*stored in a decimal*, for instance), you probably want to specify `currencyValue.ToString("C")` which takes the default locale into account.

Note, you may also want to pass a Locale specifier if you need results in other currencies.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx for more details.

Comment: I get this error when i specify .ToString("C") "No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguements "

Comment: @pacheco See the ToString documentation for the specific class. Only the form `ToString()` is defined on `object`. Other overloads are type-specific (e.g. defined on *decimal* or *FooBar*, etc)

Comment: Looks like @Mike C. got to you first.  Good luck.